# Explain unexpected result in MATCH () AGAINST ()

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a database with a fulltext column `name`. I made a query

```
SELECT name, MATCH (name) AGAINST ('breaking bad') AS score
FROM files
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('breaking bad');
```

So that I can see matching score of results. I saw,

```
name
----------------------------------------------------  score-----------
Breaking Down.mp3-----------------------------------  5.59644222259521
Breaking Benjamin - Until The End.mp3---------------  5.53353023529053
aaf-breaking.bad.s03e10.fly.English.srt-------------  5.47201633453369
Breaking Bad Season 3 Episode 03 - I.F.T..avi-------  5.47201633453369
```

I thought row containing both `breaking` and `bad` will score higher. Can anyone please explain this behavior?

**UPDATE**

I got this. It is ignoring `bad` as it is less than 4 characters. Can anyone suggest how I can include that in my search also?

Comment: I recently answered a related (but not the same) question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96847/30545 including some best practices and common issues with FULLTEXT.

Comment: @jynus, that is a beautiful post. I know that Boolean mode can be used to return keywords occurring in more than  50% columns. But have you any idea about this minimum 4 character restriction? How to change `ft_min_word_len`?

Comment: (Assuming MyISAM) set `ft_min_word_len = 3` on your `my.cnf`/`my.ini`, one the `[server]` or `[mysqld]` section and restart the server. You may have to recreate your indexes to take effect. @SouravGhosh

Comment: So, I need root access? I can never do that on a shared hosting; right? :(

Comment: @SouracGhosh Unless you can change somehow the configuration of the server, I'm afraid not- send a support to your hosting to see if they can do something about it.